# Using "org.springframework.batch.admin.integration.JobNameToJobRestartRequestAdapter" restart Batch Job

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, restart

Can anyone provide me the details as how to implement the "JobNameToJobRestartRequestAdapter" Class API  for restarting the failed job by providing the name of the job that needs to be executed.

I created the context-xml file

```
    <int:channel id="job-launches" />
    <int:channel id="job-restarts" />

     <int:service-activator id="restartJobClassProperties" input-channel="job-restarts" output-channel="job-requests">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.admin.integration.JobNameToJobRestartRequestAdapter">
            <property name="jobLocator" ref="jobRegistry" />
            <property name="jobExplorer" ref="jobExplorer" />
        </bean>
    </int:service-activator>

    <bean id="jobRegistry" class="org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.JobLocator">
        <property name="name" value="JobNameGoesHere" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jobExplorer" class="org.springframework.batch.core.explore.JobExplorer" />
```

While executing the main class which is reading this context.xml file I am getting below error:

Error creating bean with name

> 'org.springframework.integration.config.ServiceActivatorFactoryBean#0':
>   Cannot create inner bean
>   'org.springframework.batch.admin.integration.JobNameToJobRestartRequestAdapter#0'
>   of type
>   [org.springframework.batch.admin.integration.JobNameToJobRestartRequestAdapter]
>   while setting bean property 'targetObject'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.batch.admin.integration.JobNameToJobRestartRequestAdapter#0'
>   defined in class path resource
>   [META-INF/spring/restart-job-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to
>   bean 'jobRegistry' while setting bean property 'jobLocator'; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'jobRegistry' defined in class path
>   resource [META-INF/spring/restart-job-context.xml]: Instantiation of
>   bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not
>   instantiate bean class
>   [org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.JobLocator]: Specified
>   class is an interface

I want to implement the functionality for defining the batch job name which I would like to restart and the properties can be extracted from the jobexplorer based on the last executed step.

Answer (score 0):

`JobLocator` is an interface.  You can't define a bean that is just an interface.  I think you want to use a `JobRegistry`.  Below is what Spring Batch Admin uses:

```
<bean id="jobLoader" class="org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.AutomaticJobRegistrar">
    <property name="applicationContextFactories">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.ClasspathXmlApplicationContextsFactoryBean">
            <property name="resources" value="classpath*:/META-INF/spring/batch/jobs/*.xml" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jobLoader">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.DefaultJobLoader">
            <property name="jobRegistry" ref="jobRegistry" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jobRegistry" class="org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.MapJobRegistry" />
```

The `jobRegistry` bean is a registry for the jobs to be looked up from (it does implement `JobLocator`.  The `jobLoader` registers job definitions with the registry.

Comment: Thanks for the details, I am still not getting as how will I pass the job name that needs to restarted from the last failed step.